# datetimepicker not taking runtime minDate & maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datetimepicker

I am trying to pass **startDate** and **endDate** as per my active academic value (i.e. *2016-04-01* to *2017-03-31*). I have successfully passed these values in **request** parameter and getting that on the jsp page as shown below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="startDate" value="<%=request.getParameter("startDate")%>">
<input type="hidden" id="endDate" value="<%=request.getParameter("endDate")%>">
```

Now, I am trying to use this value on the **datetimepicker** so restrict the calendar view. If I pass this value as shown below, the calendar is not getting opened.

```
<script>
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'en',
timepicker:false,
format:'Y/m/d',
closeOnDateSelect:true,
minDate:$('#startDate').val(),
maxDate:$('#endDate').val(),
});
</script>
```

I tried to show these values on alert as shown below and I am able to get the correct values:

```
alert($('#startDate').val() + " : " + $('#endDate').val());
```

I also tried by passing hard-coded values on calendar script as shown below and it is working fine:

```
<script>
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'en',
timepicker:false,
format:'Y/m/d',
closeOnDateSelect:true,
minDate:'2016/04/01',
maxDate:'2017/03/31',
});
</script>
```

**The Problem in Short:** The calendar is not functioning if I try to use minDate and maxDate from the values that I stored on hidden variable.

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you please share the jquery plugin you have used for datetimepicker?

Comment: @RahulPatel Using [link](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

Comment: Your formats are different.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli I checked that using alert tag and the values fetched from Database  seems to be of the same  format that I used to show while using hard coding.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli Yes, It's working now. That was an format issue. Thanks :)